# Python dictionary comprehension very slow

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary `d1` and a list `l1`.

The dictionary keys are strings, and the values are Objects I have defined myself. If it helps, I can describe the Object in more detail but for now, the objects have a list attribute `names`, and some of the elements of `name` may or may not appear in `l1`.

What I wanted to do was to throw away any element of the dictionary `d1`, in which the `name` attribute of the object in said element does not contain any of the elements that appear in `l1`.

As a trivial example:

```
l1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'horse', 'elephant', 
      'zebra', 'lion', 'snake', 'fly']

d1 = {'1':['dog', 'mouse', 'horse','orange', 'lemon'],
      '2':['apple', 'pear','cat', 'mouse', 'horse'], 
      '3':['kiwi', 'lime','cat', 'dog', 'mouse'], 
      '4':['carrot','potato','cat', 'dog', 'horse'], 
      '5':['chair', 'table', 'knife']}
```

so the resulting dictionary will be more or less the same but the elements of each list will be the key-value pairs from `1` to `4` excluding the fruit and vegetables, and will not contain a 5th key-value par as none of the furniture values appear in `l1`.

To do this I used a nested list/dictionary comprehension which looked like this:

```
d2 = {k: [a for a in l1 if a in d1[k]] for k in d1.keys()}
print(d2)

>>>>{'1': ['dog', 'mouse', 'horse'], 
     '3': ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'], 
     '2': ['cat', 'mouse', 'horse'], 
     '5': [], 
     '4': ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']}

d2 = {k: v for k,v in d2.iteritems() if len(v)>0}
print(d2)

>>>>{'1': ['dog', 'mouse', 'horse'], 
     '3': ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'], 
     '2': ['cat', 'mouse', 'horse'],  
     '4': ['cat', 'dog', 'horse'],}
```

This seems to work, but for big dictionaries, 7000+ items, it takes around 20 seconds to work through. In and of itself, not horrible, but I need to do this inside a loop that will iterate 10,000 times, so currently it's not feasible. Any suggestions on how to do this quickly?

Comment: Note to everyone: He is using python 2.7 not 3 due to use of `itertitems`, don't let the `print()` fool you

Comment: python 2.7 has dict comprehensions?

Comment: @Claudiu Yes they were backported

Comment: +1 for providing completely copy-pastable example

Comment: There are several reasons why this runs slow, firstly for a dict you can iterate through like `for k in d1`. Dictionaries iterate over the keys by default and in Python 2.7 `dict.keys` returns a list. Another reason is that you are checking a list for memebership, you never really want to do this since it runs in O(N). However, checking a set for membership takes O(1).

Comment: Overwhelming response everybody. Thanks for the help. There are lots of things to try here. I'll start by changing all the lists to sets. Bad habbits carried over from other languages really hold you back. Stupid R!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are effectively computing the set intersection of each list occuring in the dictionary values with the list `l1`.  Using lists for set intersections is rather inefficient because of the linear searches involved.  You should turn `l1` into a set and use `set.intersection()` or set membership tests instead (depending on whether it is acceptable that the result is a set again).

The full code could look like this:

```
l1 = set(l1)
d2 = {k: [s for s in v if s in l1] for k, v in d1.iteritems()}
d2 = {k: v for k, v in d2.iteritems() if v}
```

Instead of the two dictionary comprehensions, it might also be preferable to use a single `for` loop here:

```
l1 = set(l1)
d2 = {}
for k, v in d1.iteritems():
    v = [s for s in v if s in l1]
    if v:
        d2[k] = v
```

Comment: For full efficiency I would change your first code to `>>> d2 = ((k, [s for s in v if s in l1]) for k, v in d1.iteritems())
>>> d2 = {k: v for k, v in d2 if v}`.

Comment: @jamylak: Do you think this will be noticably faster than the `for` loop?  I for one think it's at least ntoicably uglier. :)

Comment: Well it will be more efficient than the code you have for your first code right now which will run through d2 again. Not sure about second, would have to `timeit`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not the dict comprehension, but the nested list comprehension within that. You are iterating over the same keys every time. This sort of thing is better done with sets.

```
s1 = set(l1)
d2 = {k: list(s1.intersection(v)) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Comment: For more efficiency use `iteritems`

Comment: It will also be more efficient if the values in `d1` and `d2` are allowed to be sets.

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'horse', 'elephant', 
      'zebra', 'lion', 'snake', 'fly']

d1 = {'1':['dog', 'mouse', 'horse','orange', 'lemon'],
      '2':['apple', 'pear','cat', 'mouse', 'horse'], 
      '3':['kiwi', 'lime','cat', 'dog', 'mouse'], 
      '4':['carrot','potato','cat', 'dog', 'horse'], 
      '5':['chair', 'table', 'knife']}

def gen_items(valid_name_set, d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        intersection = valid_name_set.intersection(v)
        if intersection: # not empty
            yield (k, intersection)

print dict(gen_items(set(l1), d1))
```

Output:

```
{'1': set(['dog', 'horse', 'mouse']),
 '2': set(['cat', 'horse', 'mouse']),
 '3': set(['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']),
 '4': set(['cat', 'dog', 'horse'])}
```

Alternatively:

```
from itertools import ifilter
from operator import itemgetter
set_l1 = set(l1)
d2 = dict(ifilter(itemgetter(1), 
                  ((k, set_l1.intersection(v)) for k, v in d1.iteritems())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set`:

```
>>> l1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'horse', 'elephant',
      'zebra', 'lion', 'snake', 'fly']
>>> d1 = {'1':['dog', 'mouse', 'horse','orange', 'lemon'],
      '2':['apple', 'pear','cat', 'mouse', 'horse'],
      '3':['kiwi', 'lime','cat', 'dog', 'mouse'],
      '4':['carrot','potato','cat', 'dog', 'horse'],
      '5':['chair', 'table', 'knife']}
>>> l1_set = set(l1)
>>> d2 = dict((k, set(d1[k]) & l1_set) for k in d1.keys())
>>> d2
{'1': set(['horse', 'mouse', 'dog']), '3': set(['mouse', 'dog', 'cat']), '2': set(['horse', 'mouse', 'cat']), '5': set([]), '4': set(['horse', 'dog', 'cat'])}
>>> d2 = dict((k, v) for k,v in d2.iteritems() if v)
>>> d2
{'1': set(['horse', 'mouse', 'dog']), '3': set(['mouse', 'dog', 'cat']), '2': set(['horse', 'mouse', 'cat']), '4': set(['horse', 'dog', 'cat'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert `l1` to a `set` and slightly modify the dict comprehension, you can get this working roughly three times faster:

```
l1 = set(['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'horse', 'elephant', 
      'zebra', 'lion', 'snake', 'fly'])

d1 = {'1':['dog', 'mouse', 'horse','orange', 'lemon'],
      '2':['apple', 'pear','cat', 'mouse', 'horse'], 
      '3':['kiwi', 'lime','cat', 'dog', 'mouse'], 
      '4':['carrot','potato','cat', 'dog', 'horse'], 
      '5':['chair', 'table', 'knife']}

d2 = {k: [a for a in d1[k] if a in l1] for k in d1.keys()}
print(d2)
```

Here's how you can benchmark the performance:

```
import timeit

t = timeit.Timer(
    "d2 = {k: [a for a in l1 if a in d1[k]] for k in d1.keys()}",
    "from __main__ import (d1, l1)",
    )
print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number=100000)/100000)

t = timeit.Timer(
    'd2 = {k: [a for a in d1[k] if a in l1] for k in d1.keys()}',
    "from __main__ import (d1, l1)",
    )
print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
```

I'm assuming here that you don't have control over `d1`, and that converting all values of `d1` to sets prior to the filtering is too slow.